# Flutter Slang: "key" in <en> is linked to "otherKey" but "otherKey" is undefined

Tags: flutter, dart, internationalization

I'm using the Slang package to do i18n in a Flutter app. I've gone for separate json files as I think it looks a little bit cleaner. I want to use a linked translation, but it keeps on failing saying that the linked key is undefined, whereas it is

My JSON file (`common.i18n.json`):

```
{
    "nMatches": "Matches ({{number}})",
    "settingsLower": "settings",
    "matchingText(plural, param=number)": {
        "one": "1 result matching your @:settingsLower",
        "other": "{{number}} result matching your @:settingsLower"
    }
}
```

The `@:settingsLower` is indeed set and absolute, but it cannot be found.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had to also prefix the name of the file before it would work:

```
{
    "nMatches": "Matches ({{number}})",
    "settingsLower": "settings",
    "matchingText(plural, param=number)": {
        "one": "1 result matching your @:common.settingsLower",
        "other": "{{number}} result matching your @:common.settingsLower"
    }
}
```

i.e. `@:common.settingsLower`

Comment: what if the files are in a folder?